# Jackson - How to unwrap root from output JSON

Tags: json, serialization, jaxb, jackson

I am using following mapper

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper ();
mapper.configure(Feature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
AnnotationIntrospector primary = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector();
AnnotationIntrospector secondary = new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector();
AnnotationIntrospector pair = new AnnotationIntrospector.Pair(primary, secondary);
mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(pair);
```

And serializing following class to JSON

```
public class MyList {
    @JsonProperty("samples")
    List<Module> sampleList;

    public List<Module> getSampleList() {
        return sampleList;
    }

    public void setSampleList(List<Sample> sampleList) {
        this.sampleList = sampleList;
    }
}
```

But I am getting the following output:

```
{"MyList ":{"samples":[ ... ]}}
```

But I do not want this `MyList`. I am expecting:

```
"samples":[...]
```

How can I tell Jackson to include the root only when it is specified explicitely?

Comment: i can not exclude mapper.configure(Feature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
because it is required for other classes where i have explicitly provided the root

Comment: It looks like there is no ability to disable wrapping for specific classes. You can consider to have two object mappers, or switch to Jackson 2.x and use @JsonRootName annotation on the types which you want to be wrapped.